# Как разделить предложение в python, сохраняя разделители?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, split, re

У меня есть вариант кода:

```
text = 'здравствуйте убрать из счета позицию 1 добавить 2 убрать 3. добавить 4 жду исправленный счет'

patterns = r'(убрать)|(удалить)|(добавить)|(прибавить)|(изменить)'
re.split(patterns, text)
```

Результат:

```
['здравствуйте  ',
 'убрать',
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 ' из счета позицию 1 ',
 None,
 None,
 'добавить',
 None,
 None,
 ' 2 ',
 'убрать',
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 '3. ',
 None,
 None,
 'добавить',
 None,
 None,
 '4 жду исправленный счет']
```

Мне нужен вывод без "None" и чтобы было так:

```
['здравствуйте ',
 'убрать из счета позицию 1 ',
 'добавить 2 ',
 'убрать 3. ',
 'добавить 4 жду исправленный счет']
```

Либо если у меня текст такой:

```
text = 'здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать 2 добавить   3. убрать 4 добавить жду исправленный счет'
```

То разделить вот так:

```
['здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать ',
 '2 добавить ',
 '3. убрать ',
 '4 добавить',
 'жду исправленный счет']
```

Можно просто записать, как будет для первого и второго случая отдельно, не связывая оба случая.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```py
import re
text = 'здравствуйте убрать из счета позицию 1 добавить 2 убрать 3. добавить 4 жду исправленный счет'
patterns = r'(?:^|\s+)(?=убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)'
print( re.split(patterns, text) )
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/4VAG5u). Результат:

```
['здравствуйте', 'убрать из счета позицию 1', 'добавить 2', 'убрать 3.', 'добавить 4 жду исправленный счет']
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:^|\s+)` - незахватывающая подмаска, начало строки или один и более пробельных символов
- `(?=убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, сразу справа должна присутствовать одна из подстрок `убрать`, `удалить`, `добавить`, `прибавить` или `изменить`.

Чтобы находить целые слова, добавьте границу слова `\b` в конце, `(?:^|\s+)(?=(?:убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)\b)`.

---

**Для строк вторго типа** можно использовать

```
.*?(?:\d\W*(?:убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)|\Z)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/iYNQjC/1/). **Подробности**:

- `.*?` - ноль и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `\d\W*(?:убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)` - цифра, ноль и более специальных (кроме `_`, для включения этого символа используйте `[\W_]`) или пробельных символов, а потом одна из подстрок `убрать`, `удалить`, `добавить`, `прибавить` или `изменить`
  - `|` - или
  - `\Z` - конец строки
- `)` - конец незахватывающей подмаски

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/hFMIqa):

```py
import re
text = 'здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать 2 добавить   3. убрать 4 добавить жду исправленный счет'
pattern = r'.*?(?:\d\W*(?:убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить)|\Z)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.S)
print( [x.lstrip() for x in matches if x.strip() ] )
# => [
  'здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать', 
  '2 добавить', 
  '3. убрать', 
  '4 добавить',
  'жду исправленный счет'
]
```

Comment: Изменил вопрос, добавил второй вариант текста

Comment: @MaxPyankov Теперь ваш вопрос абсолютно неясен. Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Как вы определите начало и конец совпадения?

Comment: да, вы правы, поставил вопрос корректно

Comment: Можно просто записать, как будет для первого и второго случая отдельно, не связывая оба случая.

Comment: не ответили(...

Comment: @MaxPyankov вообще-то, ответил. Отдельно для первого и для второго.